# How can I add a EULA screen to my MacOS single bundle archive with Install4J?

Tags: java, install4j

I am using install4j to create a custom DMG that includes a license agreement that must be accepted in order to install.

I have checked through all of the install4j documentation and was not able to find any way to do this. This operation seems like a common use case, so I am surprised that I am having this much difficulty finding this option. Is this even possible to do with install4j or will I need to seek out alternative tools to perform this?

Update: I have decided to go with DropDMG for this task since it has a command line tool that allows for easy Gradle integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is not directly supported as of install4j 7.x, you can add additional files to the DMG on the "Installer options->DMG options and files" step. The license agreement feature of a DMG is implemented with additional files, see

http://www.owsiak.org/adding-license-to-a-dmg-file-in-5-minutes-or-less/